# Using boost.assign on collection of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, stl, boost

Consider the following snippet:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo( int Value );

    // other stuff
};

std::list< boost::shared_ptr< Foo > > ListOfFoo = list_of( 1 )( 2 )( 3 )( 4 )( 5 );
```

This does not work out of the box. What is the simplest way to make this work, or is there any method to assign values to `ListOfFoo` as simple as that?

Comment: Do you just choose the example like this or are the numbers consecutive? In that case I would suggest to use std::transform, boost::counting_iterator and binding on boost::shared_ptr and the constructor (maybe with lambda).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`boost::assign::ptr_list_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#ptr_list_of) lets you construct a [Boost pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html) with a very simple syntax. You can extend it through private inheritance so that it lets you create containers of `shared_ptr`:

```
template< class T > 
struct shared_ptr_list : boost::assign_detail::generic_ptr_list<T>
{
    typedef boost::assign_detail::generic_ptr_list<T> Base;

    template< class Seq >
    operator Seq() const 
    {
        Seq result;
        for(typename Base::impl_type::iterator it = Base::values_.begin(), e = Base::values_.end(); it != e; ++it)
            result.push_back(typename Seq::value_type(&*it));
        Base::values_.release().release();
        return result;
    }     

    template< class U >
    shared_ptr_list& operator()( const U& u )
    {
        return (shared_ptr_list&)boost::assign_detail
               ::generic_ptr_list<T>::operator()(u);
    }    
};

template< class T, class U >
shared_ptr_list<T> shared_ptr_list_of( const U& t )
{
    return shared_ptr_list<T>()(t);
}
```

It looks a bit ugly but then it's really convenient to use:

```
int main()
{
    using boost::shared_ptr;
    std::deque<shared_ptr<Foo> > deq = shared_ptr_list_of<Foo>(1)(2)(3);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for. I wonder though, if there is any easier way using the list_inserter class. The documentation says it is the key to extending the library, but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: @Space cowboy - `list_inserter` is what you would use if you are designing a new container class and you want it to interact nicely with Boost.Assign (e.g., to make `t += 2, 3` where `t` is an instance of your class). But I don't think it will be of any use here.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use `std::transform` on an array of arguments:

```
const unsigned DataSize = 5;
int data[DataSize] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > ListOfFoo;
std::transform(data, data + DataSize, std::back_inserter(ListOfFoo), &boost::make_shared<Foo, int>);
```

Perhaps looks nicer if the list is to be even larger.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > ListOfFoo = boost::assign::list_of(boost::make_shared<Foo>(1))(boost::make_shared<Foo>(2));
```

There is no implicit conversion from `Foo*` to `shared_ptr<Foo>`.

```
shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = new Foo(1); // you can't do this
shared_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo(1)); // this is ok
shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = make_shared<Foo>(1); // this is also ok
```

What you want is impossible, you have to explicitly create shared pointers and pass them to `list_of`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but calling make_shared each time looks too ugly. I want it to be as easily readable as the given example.

Answer (score 1):

Your boost::list_of requires objects of type `boost::shared_ptr<Foo>`.  So you could do it as follows:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > fooList = list_of
    (FooPtr(new Foo(1))
    (FooPtr(new Foo(2))
    (FooPtr(new Foo(3));
```

Comment: Same as Nikola. I was hoping there was a way to tell list_of to construct shared pointers from the values it is given.

Comment: I don't think that is possible as Nikola mentions in his updated answer. I think his solution with boost::make_shared is quite elegant.